# Using dart as transpiler with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, dart, transpiler

Is there a way to use the dart language with node.js? Something like livescript, coffeescript, typescript, etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, definitely. Similar question thoroughly answered on SO [use an Angular 2 Dart frontend with a Node.js backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35597480/is-it-possible-to-use-an-angular-2-dart-frontend-with-a-node-js-backend?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=twitter).

For dart node.js I/O integration there's emerging library [Node IO](https://github.com/dglogik/node_io.dart).